# How to inject a Dart file in tab?

Tags: dart

Dartium does interpret dart files and it opens plenty of fun to develop new toys, and Chrome extensions and apps. But when it comes to do scripts injection in web pages, the [`executeScript`](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs.html#method-executeScript) method only takes files supposedly one of the .css and .js formats. Files in other mimetype (typically application/dart) is offbound. Therefore, the question is pretty much naive:

Is there anyway to directly inject a Dart file?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Not a way to **directly** inject dart-files, but a workaround to inject your dart-application would be to use dart2js and than inject the compiled js-file `myDartScript.dart.precompiled.js` of your dart-script.
(Use the precompiled-version to avoid errors against the Content Security Policy)

Maybe you also have to inject `packages/browser/dart.js` and `packages/browser/interop.js`.

*Untested*